# Installing nodejs on Debian

Tags: node.js

First off, any idea why nodejs is not packaged for Debian Wheezy (The current stable version)?

Secondly, trying to install it manually, I downloaded the files and proceeded with a ./configure, make and make install. On the make install, I get this error even with sudo. I had solved a similiar issue prior (if I run ./configure it doesn't work (tries to run python code with what i assume is bash) but a "python configure" works). The 4th last error of my error message seems to prove this is the case. Should I try adding in a shebang manually to that config file? Why doesn't it come packaged with a shebang to start with?

```
make
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `node-v0.10.33/out'
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=node-v0.10.33/out/Release/lib.host:node-v0.10.33/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../deps/v8/tools/gyp; mkdir -p node-v0.10.33/out/Release/obj.target/v8_snapshot/geni; "node-v0.10.33/out/Release/mksnapshot" --log-snapshot-positions --logfile "node-v0.10.33/out/Release/obj.target/v8_snapshot/geni/snapshot.log" "node-v0.10.33/out/Release/obj.target/v8_snapshot/geni/snapshot.cc"
/bin/sh: 1: node-v0.10.33/out/Release/mksnapshot: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [node-v0.10.33/out/Release/obj.target/v8_snapshot/geni/snapshot.cc] Error 126
make[1]: Leaving directory `/node-v0.10.33/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this package is not available as one of the uninstalled supplemental packages on DVD 1 or 2?  Manually making the package can be problematic unless you have all the required libraries and include files installed which is an effort in itself.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not packaged for the stable release. Could be possible to install via backports or unstable. ALso, i have already installed the dependency requirements as listed in the README.     * GCC 4.2 or newer
    * Python 2.6 or 2.7
    * GNU Make 3.81 or newer

Comment: While it changes rarely, debian stable means whatever's considered to be stable right now - I've edited it to reflect that wheezy is stable, so users who come across this question in future don't get confused thinking its Jessie or something

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, I have no idea. Debian is *notoriously* conservative about packages, and considering nodejs is 'newfangled', maybe they don't consider it stable enough yet - There's no packages for Wheezy (stable) and Jessie (Testing) but there are packages for sid.

Rather than building the packages, you could presumably follow what [joyent suggests](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) and use the nodesource repos.